# Probability of Two Pairs ( Cards game )

Tags: probability, combinatorics, poker

**Question:** Calculate the probability of getting a two pair hand ( e.g., two 8’s, two Queens, and a Knight )

**My answer:** The probability of getting a two pair hand is :
$$ \frac{13\cdot\binom{4}{2}\cdot12\cdot\binom{4}{2}\cdot11\cdot\binom{4}{1}}{\binom{52}{5}} = \frac{396}{4165} $$
but the correct answer is :
$$ \frac{\binom{13}{2}\cdot\binom{4}{2}^2\cdot44}{\binom{52}{5}} = \frac{198}{4165} $$
which is my answer but divided by $2$. My question is why is my answer wrong, and in the correct answer where did $\binom{13}{2}$ come from?

Comment: The denominator must be $\binom{52}{\color{red}{5}}$ in both(?) cases.

Comment: what do you mean exactly ?

Comment: What does he mean?  Well... $\binom{52}{2}$ with  $2$ at the bottom there is the number of ways of choosing *two* cards out of fiftytwo.  Meanwhile $\binom{52}{5}$ is the number of ways of choosing *five* cards out of fiftytwo.  Here... we are choosing *five* cards for our hands... not just two of them.

Comment: I didn't notice that, it is typing error sorry for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are double-counting as you count any two pairs twice (as (8,8,Q,Q) and as (Q,Q,8,8)). To avoid this the correct solution suggests to use $\binom{13}2$ so that the whole pair (8,Q)$\equiv$(Q,8) is chosen.

Comment: The same situation if I want Three pair when choosing 7 cards the solution will be : –
$$ \frac{\binom{13}{3}\cdot\binom{4}{2}^3\cdot40}{\binom{52}{7}} = \frac{2376}{128639} $$
Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, this is correct (I did not check the RHS though).

Comment: Thanks for the explaining

Comment: You are welcome!